# компиляция приложения wxWidgets в Code::Blocks. Попытка обращения к неверному адресу

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

Компилировал я простинькое приложение wxWidgets в Code::Blocks и тут:

> at config\i386\host-mingw32.c|190|MapViewOfFileEx: Попытка обращения к неверному адресу. |

Comment: И кто же тот герой-телепат, кто сможет увидеть в Вашем коде ошибку? Да и причем тут вообще wxWidgets, если ошибка связана с WinAPI?

Comment: и что делать? какие данные вам нужны?

Comment: Обычно достаточно тех, что указаны в правилах данного сообщества - минимальный самодостаточный пример, иллюстрирующий ошибку или непонимание чего-то. И для начала, описание что тут вообще происходит. Что делали, что хотели получить, как докатились до такой жизни :-). И почему именно версия функции "Ex" (суффикс).

Comment: Делал я приложение. Сохранил. Потом снова открываю его но тут ето

Comment: Вы серьезно считаете, что описали ситуацию совершенно понятно для всех? Вы сами можете ответить на свой вопрос имея столько информации о происходящем? Что за приложение? Компилировалось ли оно до того? Кто вообще выдает это сообщение, которое Вы привели? Какой компилятор? Что Вы делали с компилятором (именно с компилятором, а не с CodeBlocks) в период времени между "сохранил" и "открываю"?

Comment: Приложение компилировалось. С компилятором ничего не делал в перерыве. Компилятор TDM-GCC-32

Comment: Если компилировать программу в консоли - ошибка тоже есть? При данном объеме информации могу порекомендовать снести полностью и переустановить MingW. А потом и Windows, если это не поможет :-). (Иногда у mingw бывают конфликты с антивирусами. Замечал на Касперском).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я переустановил компилятор но проблемы опять появлялись. Потом я удалил антивирус, переустановил компилятор и все заработало как надо.